# R which argument fits well to obtain nonuniform bins using "plot" to build an informative histogram

Tags: r, histogram, bin

I am new to R,I am trying to plot a cumulative frequency histogram(non-uniform bins) for a huge amount of data(few millions of positive numbers with a minimum value "1" and maximum value varies from data to data like for instance 1*10^6 or 1*10^5).I used this simple code to generate a histogram with the data.

for example:-sample data

```
[89601]     10      2      2      4      3     12      3     25     25      2
[89611]      5      5      5      2     23     22     14      8     13     10
[89621]     13     19    157      2      3      2      4      2      3     33
[89631]     22      2     14      9      2      3      3      3      8      2
[89641]      8      3      2    127      8      2     18      2      4      2
[89651]      2     13      3     34      8      2      6     10      3      7
[89661]      3      9      7      3     36      9      5      2     10     15
[89671]      7      2     23      2      2      2      2      7      6     25
[89681]      3      3      2      6     37     49     28     11      3     35
[89691]      2      2      8      3      3      2      2      4      3     12
[89701]      3      5      2      7      3      2     15      6      3     14
[89711]     13      5      3      2      2      8     34      4      4     65
[89721]      5      9     12      2     11      2      2     79      9     13
[89731]      2     66      2      9     10     22     11      2      6      3
[89741]     12      2     11      5      4      4      2      4      3      4
[89751]      2      8      9      3      2      2     84      7     11     10
[89761]      8     30     16      3     63      2      2     24     13      2
[89771]     11     37      2      9     21     21     10      2      2     49
[89781]      3      3      8      5      2     19      9      6      5      4
[89791]      4      2      9      2     10     33      5      4      2      2
[89801]      4      2      2      4      9      3     11      2      5    142
[89811]     17      2     11      4      2      8     26      2      9      8
[89821]     10      2      4      2      5      2     20      7    145     11
[89831]     22     19      8     14     18     39      3      2      3      3
[89841]      2     11     10      3      2      3      3      5      6     12
[89851]     17      5      3      8      2      2      2      2      2      5
[89861]      4      2     13      3      2      2      2      2      3      2
[89871]      4      3     21      2      6      2      8      9      7     14
[89881]      2    582      3     15     11      3     20     16      9      8
[89891]      6      2      6      7      3     20     17      2      9      5
[89901]      5     11      2     12      7      2     46      2    144      9
[89911]      2      3     36     25      3      2     16      2      2    119
[89921]      5      5     10      6      2      2      6     84     13      2
[89931]      2      6      6      2     17      3      7      4    102     48

data <- read.table("sample.txt", header=FALSE)
data <- hist(data$V1, breaks=length(data$V1), xlim=c(0,4000000))
plot(data)
```

when I did this I could get a histogram with all the data(positive numbers)on x axis and counts on y-axis.Then again I changed the limit of the x only upto the area of interest

```
plot(data, xlim=c(0,200000))
```

Like before a histogram is plotted,but using "plot" I couldn't define the number of bins and hence the histogram is not clear(not like bars which I want to be) and informative.

As I am new to this forum,I have no idea how to upload images,so I couldn't provide with the histogram.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Just use `data <- read.table("sample.txt", header=FALSE);
hist(data$V1, breaks=length(data$V1), xlim=c(0,2000000))` adjust breaks and xlim as required (see `?hist`)

Answer (score 0):

For plotting histogram you can use hist() function just this way:

```
    hist(data$V1, xlim=c(0,200000), breaks=100)
```

The breaks parameter shows, how many bars will be plotted. But this number is related to all plot, not to xlim you specified. So, at first it will make a histogram with given number of breakes and after that it will cut the part of plot you need.

But there is another way to plot the bars:

```
    data <- read.table("sample.txt", header=FALSE)
    data.hist <- hist(data$V1, breaks=length(data$V1), xlim=c(0,4000000))
    plot(data.hist$counts, type='h')
```

The hist function returns an object which represents histogram parameters.
I assume, you are interested in "counts" field.
You can plot this info in histogram-like way by defining type='h'.